# iOS: Cloudkit link is not working in iOS13

Tags: cloudkit, ios13, cloudkit-web-services, cloudkit-sharing

I am using Collaborate in my CloudKit implementation on iOS. When I share data with another user, the other user is able to click on the link in email and open it directly via Apple Mail app, but if the user tries to copy link and open it in browser or open it through Gmail which basically opens the link in browser, it throws this error in the browser without even opening my app - "iCloud has stopped responding".

I started facing this issue in iOS 13, it is working perfectly in iOS 12.

Please let me know if there is anyone else facing this issue or is there any workaround to this problem.

[image]

Thanks.